# Get the filter kwargs from Django Queryset in model manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `Company` model which hides some of its `status`. So when a user queries `Company.objects.all()` I will filter out any of special `status` I deem inappropriate.
Something like below

```
class Company(models.Model):
   name=models.TextField()
   status=models.CharField()
   ...
   objects = FilteredCompanyManager()
```

where

```
class FilteredCompanyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FilteredCompanyManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(status__in=CompanyConstants.SPECIAL_STATUS.values())
```

My question is that I want something like `Company.objects.filter(displayAllObjects=True)` to not exclude any statuses. So my amended fictional `FilteredCompanyManager` would look something like

```
class FilteredCompanyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'displayAllObjects' in super(FilteredCompanyManager, self).get_queryset().get_kwargs():
            return  super(FilteredCompanyManager, self).get_queryset()
        else:
            return super(FilteredCompanyManager, self).get_queryset().exclude(status__in=CompanyConstants.SPECIAL_STATUS.values())
```

I know I can probably do it with `objects=FilteredCompanyManager` and `allObjects=models.Manager()` but want a way where its possible in a single model manager and not with two model managers.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a manager method in which you could send the `displayAllObjects` in kwargs:

```
class FilteredCompanyManager(models.Manager):

     def get_filtered_objs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('displayAllObjects', False):
             return self.get_queryset().all()
        else:
             return self.get_queryset().exclude(status__in=CompanyConstants.SPECIAL_STATUS.values())
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
Company.objects.get_filtered_objs(displayAllObjects=True)
```

Or

```
Company.objects.get_filtered_objs()
```